# How to observe Variable<[Game]> from another Variable<[Team]>?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

How can observe a `Variable<[Game]>` from an array of teams (`Variable<[Team]>`) so that every time a `Game` comes up (`Variable<[Game]>` changes since the games array is modified), the array of `Team` should be updated accordingly, such as assigning points, victories, draw, defeats, and netGoals for the two teams involved in the game?

I have tried using `subscribe(onNext:)` but as I read, view models should not contain these kind of things as `DisposeBag`s. Since I am new to RxSwift, how can I observe changes in a `Variable<[Game]>` from a `Variable<[Team]>`?

Comment: What do you mean when you say a Game "comes up"?

Comment: I retrieve it from the server or db. I don't think, though, that the problem relies on how I get Game but rather how to link Team array to Game array

Comment: @ryantxr, see my update. What I meant by "Game comes up" is that the `Variable<[Game]>` changes, by having a game appended

Comment: Do you really need '[Team]' as a Variable? If not, better define it as *let teams = games.scan(...)* or even *games.flatMap(...)*

P.S. As of RxSwift 4.0.0, Variable is deprecated in favor of BehaviorRelay.

Answer (score 0):

> how to link Team array to Game array

Well, how about introducing `Teams` object or moving `games` to the `Team` object. You can encapsulate the push interface inside the `Team` or pass it as a dependency. It seems like the actual problem you are having is that your `Team` and `Game` are just DTOs. Make them objects instead of data structures.